# Power consumption on LPDDR4 command bus - impedance options

Tags: impedance, low-power

I'm trying to solicit and opinion on the use of the 60 ohm transmitter/transmission line/ODT for the command bus of an LPDDR4 bus would be better than 40 ohm target impedance.  The system uses an iMX8MQ and Micron 53B768M32D4DT. I only feel we need to run at 1.2GHz or even 1GHz, not 1.6GHz per the LPDDR4 specification.  I am trying to optimize for power and heat.  Any thoughts if using a 60 ohm impedance design would be suitable over 40 ohm?

Answer (score 0):

The recommendations for the trace impedance are generally based on the drive impedance of the processor's DDR I/O cell . (For example, the i.MX8MPlus is 50 ohms, Xilinx ZU5 calls out 39 ohmss).By using a higher impedance trace you have a mismatch and less than optimum signal integrity.

I would recommend using an SI analysis software tool with your board layout and the device IBIS files and take a look at the simulated signal flight and eye diagrams before committing to a final board layout.